# Is there a way to do constructor delegation using a conditional in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, delegation

I am trying to use C++11 delegation feature to construct a class conditioned on an input value. Is that even possible? The code below isn't syntactically correct but I'm putting it here for clarification purposes.

```cpp
enum MyEnum { A, B };

typedef struct {
  int val;
  MyEnum e;
} MyStruct;

class Foo {
public: 
  Foo(MyStruct a, MyStruct b) {} // a.e == A and b.e == B (assert checked)
  Foo(MyStruct x) {
    if (x.e == A) {
      return Foo(x, {0, B});
    } else {
      return Foo({0, A}, x);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Is a possibly elided call to a copy or move ctor unacceptable for `Foo`?  How about `MyStruct`?

Answer (score 8):

```
Foo(MyStruct x):
  Foo(
    (x.e==A)?x:MyStruct{0,B},
    (x.e==A)?MyStruct{0,A}:x
  )
```

is a direct way to do it.  Note that the same ctor is delegated to, but the arguments change.  This is consistent with your example, but maybe not your real problem.

---

Now, suppose you have a more complex problem.  You actually want a different constructor to be called based off the run time value?

If we want a different ctor to be called based on a run time value, we may have to rely on (hopefully elided) copy or move ctors.

The easy way is just

```
Foo(MyStruct x):
  Foo( (x.e==A)?
    Foo{x, {0,B}}:
    Foo{{0,A}, x}
  )
{}
```

where we invoke the `Foo` copy/move ctor with a different `Foo` depending on `x.e`.  This has the minor problem of blocking elision.

At this point you should stop.  Because the next step is pretty nuts.

---

Here is an overly fancy way to avoid constructing the candidate `Foo`s, and I think even permits elision (no clue if a compiler would actually do it):

```
template<class T>
struct delayed_construct {
  void const* data;
  T(*func)(void const*);
  template<class F>
  delayed_construct( F const& f ):
    data(&f),
    func([](void const* ptr)->T{
      F const& f = *static_cast<F const*>(ptr);
      return f();
    })
  {}
  T operator()() const {
    return func(data);
  }
};
struct Foo {
  explicit Foo( delayed_construct<Foo> d ):Foo(d()) {}
  Foo(MyStruct a, MyStruct b) {}
  Foo(MyStruct x):
    Foo( (x.e==A)?
      delayed_construct<Foo>{[&]()->Foo{
        return {x, {0,B}};
      }}:
      delayed_construct<Foo>{[&]()->Foo{
        return {{0,A}, x};
      }}
    )
  {}
};
```

which does a pile of really complex stuff to allow you to pick between calling two different ctors.  Even the arguments of the ctors are not evaluated if you don't pick that ctor to call.

`delayed_construct<Foo>` is basically a `std::function<F()>` that presumes its lifetime will be a temporary, and by doing so may be subject to slightly easier optimization by the compiler.

I believe that the standard allows the `Foo` constructed in the lambdas created in `Foo(MyStruct x)` to directly construct the `Foo` we are calling it from.  I may be wrong, and it is quite possible that even if I'm right, a compiler might not do it.

Comment: In your answer you assume that all three operands of the ternary operator `?:` are evaluated where it fact it does only evaluate either the second or the third argument, depending on the value of the first. It never evaluates all three operands.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky fixed I think.  Sorry about that, had a brain hiccup.

Comment: There are a couple of bugs in your templated code still: The rvalue ref for `this` must be removed on the `operator()`. The `static_cast` cannot cast away const. Hence, write `static_cast<F const*>` there. After these changes your code runs on gcc and clang both in C++11 and C++14 mode.

Comment: What makes you think, the move or copy is actually elided?

Comment: @ralph I think it would be legal to elide, as everything is a candidate, and it ends with a copy/move ctor.  I would not be surprised if it did not, or if I was wrong about it being legal.