# C++ classes: Is it possible to select a member's constructor in a constructor body? (Without doubly initializing the member)

Tags: c++, parameters, constructor, default-constructor, initialization-list

Consider this:

```
class Foo {
    private:
        Bar x;

    public:
        Foo(int a) { // no initialization here since constructor is dependent on a following if-block
            if (a==0) x=Bar(12,'a', 34);  // some (int, char, int) constructor of Bar
            else x=Bar(13); // (int) constructor of Bar
      }
}
```

What this is supposed to do, is check the value of parameter a, and initialize Bar x with a certain constructor and certain parameters depending on a's value. The problem is however, that this is of course read by the compiler as

```
        Foo(int a): Bar() { // !
            if (a==0) x=Bar(12,'a', 34);  // some Bar(int, char, int) constructor of Bar
            else x=Bar(13); // Bar(int) constructor of Bar
        }
```

The compiler adds Bar() to the initialization list, since I ommited it. It's now doubly initialized, once with its () constructor and once in the function body. But what if initializing Bar (even with its default constructor) is very costly (regarding performance) and I can't or don't want this double-initialization ?

How can I NOT initialize Bar x, until IN the actual constructor body?
And if it's not possible, how would I best work around this problem?

Adding to this: Why was C++ designed in this way? Why does it force initialization of members before the actual constructor body?

Comment: The first solution I can think of (while keeping a `Bar` stored in `Foo` directly) is making `x` a variant member and constructing it using placement new. But that would require writing all your other special member functions by hand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to do constructor delegation using a conditional in C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29173108/)

Comment: @RemyLebeau not really, since that user is asking about constructor delegation of the same class as the encompassing class, whereas in my case Foo and Bar are different classes. Not sure if that is a very important difference in this case, though.

Comment: You could pass `a` as-is to a `Bar` constructor and let it delegate to other `Bar` constructors as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are asking the wrong question, instead of trying to inhibit initialization, you should just do it, i.e. spell your ctor as:

```
Foo(int a) : x((a==0) ? Bar(12,'a', 34) : Bar(13)) {}
```

This will not cause any copies or moves (see [here](http://ideone.com/6nliAv)), and is as idiomatic as it gets.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks. (I can't upvote though, because this account is too new)

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. The members are guaranteed to be initialized yet, when in the ctor body.

The whole initialization order is well defined as:

- First, the most derived class's constructor calls the constructors of the virtual base class subobjects. Virtual base classes are initialized in depth-first, left-toright order.
- Next, direct base class subobjects are constructed in the order they are declared in the class definition.
- Next, (nonstatic) member subobjects are constructed in the order they were
  declared in the class definition.
- Finally, the body of the constructor is executed.

Answer (score 2):

You could make `x` a `std::unique_ptr<Bar>` and then allocate it as desired in the ctor.

Comment: But that would require allocating it on the free store via new, correct?

Comment: Yes; is that a problem?

Comment: Not in my case, but it's of course a slight difference to how the class might have been originally intended to work in another case. Thanks for the solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

C++ was designed this way so that the constructor actually constructs and initializes things, instead of letting you shoot yourself in the foot.

Nevertheless, since C++11 there is now a backdoor foot-shooting technique that you can use: members of anonymous unions do not get constructed unless you explicitly construct them. The code would be:

```
class Foo
{
    union 
    {
        Bar x;
    };

public:
    Foo(int a)
    {
        if (a==0) 
            new(&x) Bar(12,'a', 34);
        else
            new(&x) Bar(13);
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
         x.~Bar();
    }
};
```

To be clear this should really be a last resort. The compiler-generated copy-constructor, move-constructor etc. get defined as deleted so you would need to implement them all too if you wanted those operations available.

Comment: They also don't get destroyed, copied, or moved, unless the corresponding operation is trivial.

Comment: @T.C. have included a comment about that

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more expensive memory-wise than the anonymous union solution, but much less error-prone and doesn't incur an extra copy/move or dynamic allocation.

```
class Foo {
    private:
        std::experimental::optional<Bar> x;

    public:
        Foo(int a) {
            if (a==0) x.emplace(12,'a', 34);  // some (int, char, int) constructor of Bar
            else x.emplace(13); // (int) constructor of Bar
      }
};
```

Also, in this case `x` would be used like a pointer: `x->some_Bar_function()` and `some_function_taking_a_Bar(*x)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using delegating constructors:

```
class Foo
{
    Bar b;
    Foo( Bar b ): b(std::move(b)) { }

public:
    Foo(int a): Foo( a ? Bar(13) : Bar(12, 'a', 34) ) {}
};
```

The desired object is created during delegation and then a constructor which takes a `Bar` is invoked.  If you want to allow anyone to construct a Foo from a Bar then you could make that constructor public.

Comment: Thanks. But, wouldn't this public ctor also have Bar() added to its initialization list, therefore leading to double-initialization again?

Comment: @JMC no, the delegating constructor only invokes another constructor (and then executes the code in `{}`); it doesn't initialize any members or base classes.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that seems to be a good solution.
Would, in this case, a temporary copy of b exist in the memory, besides the Foo-instance's b, that is only deleted after the "proper" constructor is executed?

Comment: @JMC Yes, this constructs a temporary and incurs a move that cannot be elided.

Comment: @T.C. The compiler could still construct directly in `b` under the as-if rule , if the move is trivial . (IDK whether or not compilers do this)

Comment: Another possible solution would be for `Bar` to have an initializer_list constructor, or to make `Bar_proxy` that derives from `Bar` as the class member and takes `int a` as parameter and delegates

Comment: Why do the delegating ctor "dance" at all? Just spell `Foo`s ctor `Foo(int a) : x((a==0) ? Bar(12,'a', 34) : Bar(13)) {}`. Plain and simple, check [here](http://ideone.com/6nliAv)

Comment: @FabioFracassi that should be an answer rather than a comment